# How to read a specific number of bytes from a file into a bytes array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte

I would like to read 128 bytes of my file and put into a byte array to do some processing with the 128 bytes. This should iterate over the entire length of the file (i.e. everytime read the next 128 bytes and store into a bytes array and do the processing). I am currently able to read all the bytes from the file into a single byte array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get("path/t/file");
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);              }
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: [`FileInputStream.read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[]))

Comment: `byte[] bytes = new byte[128];` then.. do what he said above quite easy

Comment: ...and check the return value - the last read is typically shorter than the array length - and then comes -1 for EOF.

Comment: @3kings How do I read the second set of 128 bytes?

Comment: I posted an answer just to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You should just use FileInputStream:

```
    try {
        File file = new File("file.ext");
        RandomAccessFile data = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

        byte[] fullBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        byte[] processBytes = new byte[128];

        for (long i = 0, len = file.length() / 128; i < len; i++) {
            data.readFully(processBytes);

            // do something with the 128 bytes (processBytes).
            processBytes = ByteProcessor.process(processBytes)

            // add the processed bytes to the full bytes array
            System.arraycopy(processBytes, 0, fullBytes, processBytes.length, fullBytes.length);

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // catch exceptions.
    }
```

Comment: *... should iterate over the entire length of the file.* Maybe improve this a bit?

Comment: As in I read the first 128 bytes from the file. Then read the next 128 bytes... Keep doing this till I reach the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do.

```
public void byteStuff()
    {
        File file= new File("PATHT TO FILE");
        FileInputStream input= new FileInputStream(file);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[128];

        while((input.read(bytes)) != -1)
        {
            //byte array is now filled. Do something with it.
            doSomething(bytes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that this does not necessarily read 128 bytes at a time - it reads *up to* 128 bytes.

Comment: @AndyTurner ahh okay so would there be a way to read 128 bytes at a time? Maybe like in the below answer?

Comment: No, that answer has the same issue as it stands. You need to check the number of bytes read (the return value of `read`), and then keep reading until you've got 128 bytes.

Comment: @Andy Turner How to check the return value of the read function? Would you be able to edit the above code to make it read 128 bytes? Thanks!